# value in GET variable Lost on page load

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Value in GET variable Lost on page load ,I want to store GET variable value for long time such that it changes only request from a view page

help me how can i store Value in $_GET[] unless it changes on requesting

```
        function get_data($limit,$offset )
        {

    //$type = $this->input->post('data');


    $this->db->select('S_Name,P_Name,P_Price');
    //$this->db->from();

    $this->db->join('item_info', 'P_Id = I_ProductId ');
    $this->db->join('order_info', 'I_OrderId = O_Id');
    $this->db->join('shops_info', 'O_ShopId = S_Id');

    $this->db->where('S_Id',$_GET['shopId']);
    $query = $this->db->get('product_info',$limit,$offset);

    return $query->result();    
}
```

Comment: does your url change on page load? that is what could cause the get values to change.

Comment: Also, are you sure there no redirection going on elsewhere in the code ?

Comment: you will want to use $_SESSION to keep a variable for a user.

Comment: Yes ,when i click on 2nd int value to show more data ,query string ?shopId=1 disappers, this value is i m geeting in GET value ,can u tell how can i stop to change url?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it for a few page reloads later, I would use sessions. You can assign the $_GET variable to a session at the beginning and then do what you want with this.

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_GET['shopId'])){
$_SESSION['shopId'] = $_GET['shopId'];
}
```

Comment: I tried Session ,but giving same problem onclick that 'index undefined :shopId'

Comment: I m doing this in Controller session_start();
$_SESSION['shopId'] = $_GET['shopId'];    and  $this->db->join('item_info', 'P_Id = I_ProductId ');
  $this->db->join('order_info', 'I_OrderId = O_Id');
  $this->db->join('shops_info', 'O_ShopId = S_Id');
  
     $this->db->where('S_Id',$_SESSION['shopId']);
  $query = $this->db->get('product_info',$limit,$offset); in model

Comment: Hey Altin , i m doing same as u answered in controller and using $_SESSION['shopId'] in db where clause ,bur not helping

Comment: hmm... sorry if i couldn't help you. I updated my answer, maybe it will work now :)