# GET variable Value lost ,want to store (causing me trouble in pagination of data ,because GET value lost on page load)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I m working on php codeIgniter i found an issue while paging a datatable, I take the get value from a view through query string and recevie asa GET value and use to fetch data from data base in where clause,Problem i have facing is that i have done paging of the retrieved data ,on another view 1st set of data comes fine ,but on number 2nd click shows error that GET value is empty ,Paging works as get value from database with offset and limit but when GET value lost after 1st page load ,shows error ,plzz help me some body so that i can store $_GET['value'] some where for long time unless i select another value from a view.!!

GET variable Value lost ,want to store so that changes only on requesting (causing me problem in pagination of data ,because GET value lost on page load)

Model

```
        function get_data($limit,$offset )
        {

    //$type = $this->input->post('data');


    $this->db->select('S_Name,P_Name,P_Price');
    //$this->db->from();

    $this->db->join('item_info', 'P_Id = I_ProductId ');
    $this->db->join('order_info', 'I_OrderId = O_Id');
    $this->db->join('shops_info', 'O_ShopId = S_Id');

    $this->db->where('S_Id',$_GET['shopId']);
    $query = $this->db->get('product_info',$limit,$offset);

    return $query->result();    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [value in GET variable Lost on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153765/value-in-get-variable-lost-on-page-load)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, unless you save it to a session, you'll have to pass the get var between all the pagination links in order to keep the parameter there.

Comment: And you should probably be passing that value to your model instead of having your model directly access `$_GET`.